# Any tool to differentiate a tensor wrt another tensor?

Tags: matlab, wolfram-mathematica, sympy

I have been dealing with continuum mechanics, and there are a lot of operations where I need to get the derivative of a tensor with respect to another tensor. I'd love to try to do that symbolically, on computers.

For example, the elasticity tensor c = d(2nd PK stress) / d(strain tensor), while both 2nd PK stress tensor and strain tensor are 3x3 matrices, and the resulting elasticity tensor is 3x3x3x3 4th order tensor.

I tried to use sympy, but it seems that the most it would support is a matrix (tensor of order 2). The ndarray in numpy is simply not in sympy.

I used to use matlab, and am now aware of any way that it would work in matlab either.

Therefore, I was wondering that, is there any tool that is available for this purpose? Can mathematica do that?

Thanks a lot in advance!

-Shawn

Comment: Numerically or symbolically? The difference is quite important. Also, please define the operation precisely because "derivative of a tensor wrt another tensor" does not mean much.

Comment: @Krastanov Thanks for responding! As I have noted in the 1st paragraph of the question, I mean symbolically. For the operation, it can be roughly understood as "every component of one tensor being differentiated wrt everycomponent of the other tensor". This is more precisely defined in every tensor analysis book though. And also, I have given a brief example in the second paragraph of my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to do this in python would be to use numpy arrays using `dtype=object` so that you can fill them with sympy expressions instead of numbers. However you will have to write all the convenience methods yourself (but they would be extremely simple, just looping already implemented sympy function over the numpy arrays).

This obviously can be done in Mathematica as well or in Matlab if you install the necessary symbolic packages.

Mathematica also has packages for tensor analysis, but they would be an overkill for the problem that you are describing. In the same way, there are various packages for differential geometry and tensor analysis in SymPy, but again, they would be an overkill.